# Finding the smallest number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, min

I am trying to create random numbers in an array and then find the smallest number in that array.  How do I modify my code to make it work?

```
using namespace std; 

int one, two, three, four; 

int main(){

  srand (time(NULL));

  one = rand() % 6 + 1;

  two = rand() % 6 + 1;

  three = rand() % 6 + 1;

  four = rand() % 6 + 1;

  int myelement [4] = {four, three, two, one};

  cout << myelement, myelement[+4] << endl;

  cout << min_element(myelement, myelement[+4]);

  return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [std::min_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) function does not take a dereferenced pointer as an argument which is what you are doing with `myelement[+4]`. Pass in the iterators and return an iterator instead:

```
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(myelement), std::end(myelement));
std::cout << *it;
```

Make sure you include the [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header.

Also, this:

```
 cout << myelement, myelement[+4] << endl;
```

is wrong for a number of reasons.

This:

```
cout << myelement;
```

does not print out a first element. It prints the pointer value as your array gets converted to a pointer when used in a function.

This:

```
 cout << myelement[+4];
```

does not print the fourth element value but causes undefined behaviour as there is no such element as `myelement[+4]`, only `myelement[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are already finding the smallest number. You are just not taking into account that `min_element()` takes *iterators* as input and returns an *iterator* as output. You are not passing a valid iterator in the 2nd parameter, and you need to dereference the output iterator to get the actual number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int one = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int two = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int three = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int four = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int myelement [4] = {four, three, two, one};
    cout << *min_element(myelement, myelement+4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is `<cstdlib>` and `<ctime>`. `<algorithm>` is still missing.

Comment: ur actually amazing